# jquery hide one div, show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following website: http://karlstrup.dk.server15.exaweb.dk/boliger/ (username and pass server15)
I am having a challenge. I have 5 divs, one set to display:none; in the css when the page loads I have five corresponding links. When the user clicks on link1 I would like to show div1 and hide other divs. And when the user clicks on link2 I would like to show div2 and hide others in the same way , want to repeat functionality for the other divs to.

I have not been able to get this to work! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what's the un and pass?

Comment: why not just post your code here? most SO users won't visit unknown websites. plus, if the code on your website changes someday, then your question makes no sense anymore.

Comment: username and pass is server15 (already mention)

Comment: @Shehryar That's not the point. You've to generalize your question in a own code example otherwise no one is able to help you. It's like saying "this screw in this car has to be screwed in." Which screw, which car, what have you tried?

Comment: Code is two long .. but i create five divs to take idea from it ..<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

<div id="flip2">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel2">Hello world!</div>

<div id="flip3">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel3">Hello world!</div>

<div id="flip4">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel4">Hello world!</div>

<div id="flip5">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel5">Hello world!</div>

Comment: i want that when i click on (Click to slide the panel down or up) button or div so the data (show and hide).

Comment: Bootstrap nav pills already do what u are trying to accomplish, all u have to do is use the html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/3z5mun1p/5/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
        <li>Link 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
    <div id="1">Link 1 contents</div>
    <div id="2" class="inactive">Link 2 contents</div>
    <div id="3" class="inactive">Link 3 contents</div>
    <div id="4" class="inactive">Link 4 contents</div>
    <div id="5" class="inactive">Link 5 contents</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.links').find('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            var link = $(this).html(); 
            var linksObj = link.split(" ");
            $('.tabs').find('div').hide();
            $('#' + linksObj[1]).show();
        });
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.inactive {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Above is just an example you can change it the way you want!

Comment: yes Deepak Biswal some thing like that but i want to display the content (text) of link 1 under Link 1 item and Link two content under link 2 item..

Comment: You can do that with CSS and HTML to put link content just below the link!

Answer (score 0):

On every button click hide all the the tabs and then show the desired tab. See code below.

```
$(".uk-button").click(function(){
  $(".uk-panel").hide();
  var id = $(this).data("uk-toggle");
  $(id.target).show();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below a working example, feel free to change accordingly to your needs.

Basically you can solve your requirement in this way:

- whenever you click a link hide all divs
- and shows the div linked to clicked link

You an `style.display` in order to set the visibility of your divs.

Please note: solution is done using vanilla JS, no jquery or other library is needed in this solution.

Live example:
https://jsbin.com/betecegoro/edit?html,output

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .panel {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        (function (window) {
            window.app = {
                items: [0,1,2,3],
                start: function () {
                    this.addListeners();
                    this.hidePanels();

                },
                hidePanels: function () {
                    this.items.forEach(function (item) {
                        var elm = document.getElementById('panel-' + item);
                        elm.style.display = 'none';
                    });
                },
                showPanel: function (id) {
                    var elm = document.getElementById('panel-' + id);
                    elm.style.display = '';
                },
                addListeners: function () {
                    this.items.forEach(function (item) {
                        var elm = document.getElementById('link-' + item);
                        elm.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                            this.hidePanels();
                            var id = elm.id.split('-')[1];
                            this.showPanel(id);
                        }.bind(this))
                    },this);
                }
            };

        })(window);

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="window.app.start();">
    <div>
        <a id="link-0" href="#">Show Panel 0 and hide others</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="link-1" href="#">Show Panel 1 and hide others</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="link-2" href="#">Show Panel 2 and hide others</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="link-3" href="#">Show Panel 4 and hide others</a>
    </div>
    <div id="panel-0" class="panel">Content Panel 0</div>
    <div id="panel-1" class="panel">Content Panel 1</div>
    <div id="panel-2" class="panel">Content Panel 2</div>
    <div id="panel-3" class="panel">Content Panel 3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you're asking:

```js
$('div[id^=flip]').click(function() {
  $('div[id^=panel]').hide();
  $(this).next('div[id^=panel]').show('slow');
});
```

```css
div[id^=flip] {
  height: 25px;
}
div[id^=panel] {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip2">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel2">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip3">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel3">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip4">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel4">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip5">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel5">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: yes this is what i want ... but after pasting code in wordpress it generates an error (console). And the code not works in wordpress but works fine in simple html.